# Why do ResultSet APIs throw 'SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set'?

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, sqlexception

I am adding a basic login form to my project and it gives me this error **java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set."** when the username or password doesn't match the data in the MySQL database.

If I check the result set is empty or not then the code inside that if statement does not work. However, my code runs fine without that if statement.

PLease find that section of the code below

```
String studentNumber = userText.getText();
String password = String.valueOf(passText.getPassword()); 

String executeQuery = "select * from login where studentNumber='"+studentNumber+"' and password ='"+password+"'" ;
ResultSet rSet = connObject.queries.executeQuery(executeQuery);// stores result of query

if(!rSet.next()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Number/ Password not found :(");
}
if(studentNumber.equals(rSet.getString("studentNumber"))){
    if(password.equals(rSet.getString("password"))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you are now logged in :)");

        loginFrame.setVisible(false);
        new operationClass();
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "password not found :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know why this question is being disliked, is there anything that's unclear?

Comment: Aren't you missing an else block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` has side-effects, you can't call it *twice*.

You need to call it exactly once and then if it returned `false`, do one thing, and if `true`, do another. All you need is, instead of the commented out code, use an `else`.

Also, use bcrypt or other password hashes, do not put passwords in a database. Also, connections and resultsets need try-with-resources protected. Also, your app is insecure (it has an SQL injection attack).

NB: Just to head off the "But it's just for school". Well, you tell me: What's the point of learning boneheaded security practices? You can search the web for these terms ("SQL injection attacks", "password hash", "bcrypt", etcetera). You'll learn crucial information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was planning to insert the password manually in MySQL database using  (sha1) however I was not sure how would I compare that value with the text entered by the user since sha1 generates a bunch of random characters and that would not match with the user entered text. Any suggestions ?

Comment: SHA1 is not suitable for hashing passwords. You want PBKDF, Argon, bcrypt, scrypt, one of those. You can find any of many tutorials. These take care of everything for you - you just take the user's password, take the thing you stored in the database, and the library tells you if they match or not (and for new users, you hand the library the new password, and the library gives you a string to store in the DB).